# Foreign key codes are not working in migrations of Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-8

I tried to make a foreign key, however, it is not working.

**Posts Migration**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title", 60);
            $table->string("description", 200);
            $table->text("content");
            $table->string("photo");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")
                ->on("users")->onDelete("cascade");
        });
    }
    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

**Users Migration**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("name", 30);
            $table->string("email")->unique();
            $table->string("password");
            $table->string("username")->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a "user_id" column for posts that should be connected with an id of a user via a foreign key. But, when I migrate I am getting errors like the following

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `mytest_db`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
> formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint
> `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users`
> (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> at
> W:\domains\mytest.uz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
> 674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 677▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
> 679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 680▕             );
> 681▕         }
> 682▕
>
> 1
> W:\domains\mytest.uz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mytest_db`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint
> is incorrectly formed")")
>
> 2
> W:\domains\mytest.uz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
> PDOStatement::execute()

Comment: What order are the migrations run?  CreateUsersTable should run before CreatePostsTable

Comment: Thank you Erich you helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys cannot be defined on tables that don't yet exist.

Laravel performs migrations in filename order, prepending timestamp to the migration name.
Make sure that `CreatePostsTable` migration comes *after* the migration for `CreateUsersTable`.